# Odd encoding issue with Ã¶

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, encoding, character-encoding

I am trying to exract the following character as unicode from a sql server 2008 db

the character should be umlaut

Here is the schema information from the table

```
character_set_name    collation_name

iso_1                 SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

and here is my select statement

```
select 
    StudentName

from GenData.dbo.StudentInfo 
where StudentID = 105
order by studentname COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Pref_CP850_CI_AS
```

However the above still produces:

```
Ã¶
```

does anyone know what i am doing wrong or how to extract this character?  your help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the column from `char` or `varchar` to `nvarchar` it should resolve the issue going forward.

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ALTER COLUMN MyField nvarchar(1234)
```

Be mindful of using nvarchar in sql queries.

```
  'this is varchar'
  N'but this is nvarchar'
```

As far as recovering the information already skewed, it is often a difficult process of trial and error from my experience. You could try inputting characters into varchar fields and using that information to scrub your data.

```
INSERT INTO #transpose
SELECT '' low, N'Ü' high
UPDATE #transpose SET low = high

Update MyTable 
SET MyFIELD = REPLACE(MyField, low, high) 
FROM MyTable 
CROSS JOIN #transpose
```